# Deploy to Azure from CircleCI

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, circleci

I'm using CircleCI for the first time and having trouble publishing to Azure.

The docs don't have an example for Azure, they have an example for AWS and a note for Azure saying "To deploy to Azure, use a similar job to the above example that uses an appropriate command."

If anybody has an example YAML file that would be great, if not a nudge in the right direction would be handy. So far I think I've worked out the following.

1. I need a config that will install the Azure CLI
2. I need to put my Azure deployment credentials in an environment variable and
3. I need to run a deploy command in the YAML file to zip up all the right files and deploy to my Azure app service.

I have no idea if the above is correct, or how to do it, but that's my understanding right now.

I've also posted this on [the CircleCi forum](https://discuss.circleci.com/t/deploy-to-azure-from-circleci/23203).

EDIT: Just to add a little more info, the AWS version of the config file used the following command:

```
- run:
      name: Deploy to S3
      command: aws s3 sync jekyll/_site/docs s3://circle-production-static-site/docs/ --delete
```

So I guess I'm looking for the Azure equivalent.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you because I don't use Azure but I can say, this is not CircleCI specific. However you would deploy to Azure on a Linux/Unix-like machine, that's how you would do it here. I would read through the Azure CLI Docs and follow their instructions.

Comment: Thanks @FelicionoTech , I'm a Windows user so I guess I'm having trouble distinguishing between Circle, Yaml, Azure commands and Linux command line instructions. I will try all those things later today.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is that on the azure management console you setup as deployment from source control and you can follow this two links

https://medium.com/@strid/automatic-deploy-to-azure-web-app-with-circle-ci-v2-0-1e4bda0626e5
https://www.bradleyportnoy.com/how-to-set-up-continuous-deployment-to-azure-from-circle-ci/

if you want to do the copy of the files from ci to the iis server or azure you will need ssh access the keys etc.. and In the Dependencies section of circle.yml you can have a line such as this:

`deployment:
  production:
    branch: master
    commands:
      - scp -r circle-pushing/* username@my-server:/path-to-put-files-on-server/`

“circle-pushing” is your repo name, which is whatever it’s called in GitHub or Bitbucket, and the rest is the hostname and filepath of the server you want to upload files to.

and probably this could help you understand it better
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/copy-files-to-linux-vm-using-scp

Comment: I wouldn't use this YAML example because it's CircleCI 1.0 syntax and not 2.0. CircleCI 1.0 will be EOL'd in August. Otherwise if you have SSH access then that final line would work.